# Sending email with nodemailer and handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, nodemailer, express-handlebars

I want to send an email using Nodemailer and Handlebars but I can't use a dynamic template.

Here is my setup. `template` is the template name and it looks like `sign-up-mail-template` Now when I send this email I will receive `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ubuntu/backend/src/templates/sign-up-email-template.handlebars'`

If I change the `defaultLayout` to `sign-up-email-template.hbs` will send the email without any problem but even if I request to send a different email template let's say `password-reset-template` which will be called in `mailOptions` it will send the `defaultLayout`.

Can please anyone explain to me what am I doing wrong here?

Also if `const template = "password-reset-template.hbs"` It will receive `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ubuntu/backend/src/templates/password-reset-template.hbs.handlebars'`

```
 const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
    smtpTransport({
      host: constants.EMAIL_HOST,
      port: constants.SMTP_PORT,
      secure: false,
      requireTLS: true,
      auth: {
        user: constants.EMAIL_USER,
        pass: constants.EMAIL_PASSWORD
      }
    })
  );

  const handlebarsOptions = {
    viewEngine: {
      extName: ".hbs",
      partialsDir: "./src/templates/",
      layoutsDir: "./src/templates/",
      defaultLayout: template
    },
    viewPath: path.resolve("./src/templates/"),
    extName: ".html"
  };

  transporter.use("compile", hbs(handlebarsOptions));

  const mailOptions = {
    to: email,
    from: '"Welcome" no-reply@mail.com',
    template,
    subject,
    context: {
      code: promoCode
    }
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      throw new Error(error.message);
    }
    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.message);
  });
```

Comment: i'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `main.handlebars file` like bellow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    {{{body}}}

</body>
</html>
```

`{{body}}` is where you `sign-up-email-template.handlebars` will be placed.

Hope help you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out, and remember to make your **template folder** correctly. **Default Layout** remains empty so you can set your template inside mail options.

```
const handlebarOptions = {
    viewEngine: {
      extName: '.hbs',
      partialsDir: 'views',//your path, views is a folder inside the source folder
      layoutsDir: 'views',
      defaultLayout: ''//set this one empty and provide your template below,
    },
    viewPath: 'views',
    extName: '.hbs',
  };


mailTransport.use('compile', hbs(handlebarOptions));

const mailOptions = {
        from: '"Spammy Corp." <ad.timely@gmail.com>',
        to: 'nipunkavishka@gmail.com',
        template: 'index',//this is the template of your hbs file
  };
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having some issues getting a handlebars template to work as well, and I was just wondering what is the correct way to set up the template folder? ```backend/views/template/template.hbs```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use

`extName` to `extname` in viewEngine object for partials

```
var options = {
    viewEngine: {
    extname: '.hbs',                      
    layoutsDir: 'views/layouts/',                      
    defaultLayout : 'template.hbs',                      
    partialsDir : 'views/partials/'                  
   },
   viewPath: 'views/emails/',
   extName: '.hbs'
};
```

Directory

```
=> views/layouts/template.hbs
=> views/emails/forgot-password.hbs
=> views/partials/header.hbs
                 /footer.hbs
```

In template.hbs

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        {{>header}}
        {{{body}}}
        {{>footer}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```